# r.* commands not found

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm very new to GIS and have recently installed QGIS on my mac desktop computer, running Yosemite 10.10.

I'm working with DEM data for stream network extraction, but the majority of grass raster commands are not functional. For example, when attempting a stream network extraction, I get this output:

[image: log attempting to run r.stream.extract]

It seems to me that the first major problem is that QGIS cannot find the command r.stream.extract. However, it CAN find some other (simpler) commands, such as r.aspect. I am completely unfamiliar with digging around in the guts of these types of problems and would really like to know how to remedy this problem.

Is it as simple as somehow completing my collection of r.* commands, and if so, how?

Or is there something more subtle going on here?

Comment: You didn't mention what version of QGIS you are using. I find it hard to work with GRASS plugin since QGIS 2.6, and now after upgrading to 2.8, I can't even find the plugin anymore. Therefore, my reccomendation is to use GRASS for GRASS operations.

Comment: Yea, I'm running 2.8. That's too bad it's so difficult; I thought one of the main premises of QGIS is that it is running a version of GRASS in the background and making GRASS functions more accessible for novices. Anyways, thanks for your answer, I'll just stick with GRASS.

Comment: I too liked this feature in GRASS. Honestly I couldn't figure out what exactly happened; but understood that due to GRASS updates there is no compitability between the two softwares (or at least much less compitability)